# NodeJs : Liferay api to fetch the "custom field" created for Role

Tags: node.js, api, liferay

According to my requirement in Liferay, I have created custom fields for roles and assigned it to a user. My goal is to call the JSONWS API and get these custom fields using NodeJS. I am not able to decide which API I should call.

This Url is having APIs: http://www.liferay.com/api/jsonws

I will appreciate for any kind of help.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no options to access the expando value via exposed webserveices.
Probably what you can do is that, create a custom portlet, add a dummy entity in the service builder and in that expose a method for web service. In that method call the role API and expando API , and return the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Fields are called "Expando" in the API and are modeled like virtual tables. The functionality that's exposed through webservices is ExpandoColumn and ExpandoValue. Probably the best way to figure out the parameters to give is to look at the matching database tables. Careful: You should only ever read the database and not be tempted to write to it.

I hate giving the advice to go to the database, but this is probably the quickest - at least for my explanation :)

Comment: Thanks Olaf and Danish. Your suggestions helped me to resolve my problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Please go ahead and accept one of the answers (pick Danish, as that answer was the first, if both were helpful)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a genuine solution without hitting database directly. JSONWS is having api :

```
/portal.expandovalue/get-data
```

Which helped me to get attributes assigned to a particular role.

The above API needs 5 parameters to be passed.

1. companyId:  whaterver the companyId assigned for your liferay.
2. className:  It depends upon, we created attribute for role or user

   ```
          com.liferay.portal.model.Role or com.liferay.portal.model.User
   ```
3. tableName:  CUSTOM_FIELDS
4. columnName: It is the same name you given for attribute
5. classPK:    It is nothing but your role or user ID for which you have created Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" when using @user3771220 solution, try com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.User